# Components of force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors, free-body-diagram

Why not take components of tension in the string and balance the bob's weight using further components of the 'sine' component of the tension?
[image]

Comment: You can.  Have you tried it?  It's more complicated than doing it as in the second figure.

Comment: You seem to have done both, so I don't really understand the question...

Comment: Lemme clear it, I have always seen people doing the second method, I am asking if I can do as first.

Answer (score 1):

You can always break any force you like into components, but the issue is, which way will help you once you have done it?  In this problem, you have an additional constraint that the length of the string is not allowed to change, and that means the mass has to move perpendicular to the string.  That's why it makes sense to analyze the forces perpendicular to the string, it creates a one-dimensional problem that you can solve.  If you do it the other way, you still have to worry about the forces in both directions, so it's much more complicated.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried doing it the upper (pic) way. It is getting much complicated. So that means that it cannot be solved like that?

Comment: Or if there can be a solution taking components of components of .. force?

Comment: Don't go down the road of taking components of components.   This should be solvable either way, but I've never personally tried doing it "the hard way".

Comment: I don't think he's taking components of components, he's deciding which force to break into components-- gravity or tension.  You can do the problem either way, but it's much harder if you break tension into components, because it's harder to state the constraint that the resulting motion must be perpendicular to the string.